# What is the difference between Aurora Inspector and Focus FireBug Window?

Tags: firefox, browser

Is there any difference between `Inspector` and `Focus Firebug Window` in `Aurora` Browser?

Answer (score 0):

Inspector is typically used to inspect HTML tags and elements as part of the browser window options.

Focus Firebug Window is a feature of the firebug applet so its behavior is different as they are different tools altogether.